# How to add variables to a csv file with powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add a specific user to a csv file. The file must have Name, Username, Email and Date as headers and when a user is added the specific variables are placed in the correct column. Here is what I have so far:

```
  Add-content -path C:\...\file.csv -value '"name","username","email","date"'
  $user = @($name,$username,$email,$date)
  Add-content -path C:\...\file.csv -value $user
```

(The variable name, email, username and date are defined previously and are strings)

When I run the command

```
 import-csv -path C:\...\file.csv
```

It returns the variables defined in the column Name instead of each variable being placed in it's specific header. Why is this happening?

Comment: Most of the time it's much easier to use `Export-CSV` (and `Import-CSV`) than creating the file with `Add-Content`. Could you show us the first 2-3 rows of the file?

Answer (score 2):

```
 New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    Name=$name
    Username=$username
    Email=$email
    Date=$date
 }|Export-Csv -path C:\...\file.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: Jep that's better ;)  If you take a look at the object that `Import-Csv` creates, you can see that it is an array of `[PSCustomObject]`. And that is what `Export-Csv` handles best too. The easiest way to create an array of `[PSCustomObject]` is with  `... | Select-Object`. That is if you don't need to create it from scratch...